# Check if a feature class exists in the new dataset before using lyr.replaceDataSource using python

Tags: python

I have couple of MXDs in a folder and need to update the datasource for all of them i'm using the script below in python, however, some of the feature classes are missing in the new SDE source and the script stops working when gets to a layer that can't be found. At this stage I just need the script to skip through those layers and continue updating the datasource for the rest of the layers.

## Import system modules

```
import arcpy, os
```

## find all the MXD's in the directory tree

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(r"C:\GIS\MXDs\TEST"):
    for filename in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
            print "------------------------------"
            print filename
            #open the map document
            MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
            #get all the layers
            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(MXD):
            #get the source from the layer
            if lyr.supports("workspacePath"):
                source = lyr.workspacePath
                print "%s -> %s" % (lyr, source)
                basename, extension = os.path.splitext(source)
                if extension.lower() == ".sde":
                    #This is the NEW SOURCE that you want to point to
                    datapath = r"C:\Users\24323\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\mobi_viewer_QG3.sde"
                    #replace the old path wih the new
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(r"C:\Users\24323\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\mobi_viewer_QG3.sde", "SDE_WORKSPACE" )
        #save your changes
```

## save your changes

```
        MXD.save()
        del MXD
```